# Accessing bindings variables in component controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components

I am trying to console.log myobject but I keep getting undefined. I tried using $scope.watch and $attrs.$observe. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

here is the html

```
<my-component some-data="$ctrl.data"></my-component>
```

here is the component and controller

```
module.component('myComponent', {
bindings: {
  needThisStuff: '<someData'
},
controller: Ctrl,
templateUrl:
  requirejs.toUrl('path/to/templ.html')
 });

function Ctrl(){
var self = this;
console.log(self.needThisStuff);
}
```

how can I access needThisStuff using $watch or $observe or anything else, I am using angular 1.5

Comment: Show how you set `$ctrl.data`, this is probably the issue. Component code is correct.

Comment: $ctrl.data is a object inside another components controller

Comment: if I pass to the binding data=$ctrl  I can console.log(self.data) and see the entire $ctrl object but when I do data=$ctrl.data it gives undefined.

Comment: And one more time: show how you set `$ctrl.data`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the object is undefined because your `console.log` fires as soon as the component loads.  The data hasn't been returned yet, so it is still `undefined`.

As a basic way to test this, you could wrap your console.log in a `$timeout` just to test.

To fix this, **use angular component lifecycle hooks**.  Change your `Ctrl` to be something like this:

```
function Ctrl {
    var self = this;
    this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
       console.log(changesObj.needThisStuff);
    }
}
```

`$onChanges` is called whenever one-way bindings are updated, which in this case is your `needThisStuff` variable.